# How to get id's of all children of a div

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am using lxml to scrape a particular page. I know how to grab a tag by id, but could not find how to grab the actual id attributes.

For example say the html is:

```
<div id="stuff" >
    <div id="some unknown"> xxxx </div>
    <div id="another unknown"> xxxxx </div>
</div>
```

How do I get a list

```
['some unknown', 'another unknown']
```

Is there a way of doing so using xpath specifically?

Comment: what xpath have you tried?

Comment: honestly not sure how to approach this. I tried `root.xpath('//*[@id="stuff"]/div/')` to get the divs themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `id`s of the **direct children**, you can use the following XPath query:

```
#                                       v obtain id attribute
document.xpath('//*[@id="stuff"]/*[@id]/@id')
#                 ^ #stuff tag   ^ child with id attribute
```

Here we thus first look for a `<* id="stuff">` tag, then we look for direct children (any tag) that have an `@id` and we take the `@id` from these.

This will return a list of `lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult` elements. We can however use `str(..)` to obtain the string value:

```
[str(the_id) for the_id in document.xpath('//*[@id="stuff"]/*[@id]/@id')]
```

Note that here we do note care about the type of the child. If you only want the `id`s of `<div>` children, you can use:

```
#                                         v obtain id attribute
document.xpath('//*[@id="stuff"]/div[@id]/@id')
#                 ^ #stuff tag   ^ child with id attribute
```

In case you look for **all descendants**, you simply have to add an additional slash between the `@id="stuff"` query and the children:

```
#                                        v obtain id attribute
document.xpath('//*[@id="stuff"]//*[@id]/@id')
#                 ^ #stuff tag    ^ descendant with id attribute
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, I'm going to try it out - edit - it works!